# System.Security.VerificationException Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When I try to run unit tests from one folder under my solution I get this error

*Unit Test Runner failed to run tests
System.Security.VerificationException Operation could destabilize the runtime*

When I run the unit tests for the whole solution all tests plus these ones run fine. I tried 
setting the ruleset to level1 [assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)] but that didnt work either

My assemblyinfo looks like

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CommonTest")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

[assembly: ComVisible(false)]


[assembly: Guid("d30f8726-fc9f-4cd0-986e-a2ed5ea0a5cd")]
```

and globalassemblyinfo.cs looks like

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]

[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]
```

Comment: What mocking framework are you using? Is it one of the Profiler-based ones, like Typemock, JustMock or Microsoft Moles/Fakes?

Comment: We are not mocking framework. Instead we use NSubstitute.Substitute to mock accessors.